# Receive data in nextjs app router edge functions

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am working on nextjs app router and I have an api folder inside `app` folder like `app/api/route.ts`. Below is the code I have in that `route.ts` file.

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  console.log(request.body);
  return NextResponse.json({
    name: `Gafer`,
  });
};
```

When I make a post request in react like below.

```
const Component = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
       const res = await fetch('/api', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'mine@gmail.com' })});
       const json = await res.json();
    })()
  }, []);
}
```

The above code does make a request to that endpoint however, when I use `request.body` inside the edge function above, it does not log `email: mine@gmail.com`. In fact, it logs something like below.

```
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
```

My question is how can I access the data I sent to my edge function?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing you are using Next.js 13 (App Directory); The request object now has a function to parse the body into json. You could try something like the following:

```
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/response";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const body = await request.json();
  console.log(body);
  return NextResponse.json({ name: `Gafer` });
};
```

I have also updated the type for the request object, since you will get a an error from typescript otherwise due to the lack of the `json()` function in NodeJS's `Request` type.